# VBA sort row by dates

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a file containing dates on the first row, and a column of identifiers defining a table where I fill in the employee data for the corresponding data (See picture) [image]

I want the dates to be sorted in the chronological order, but I only want to sort the dates, before I fill in the table.

I tried the following code

```
Sub sortByDates()

    Dim sumSheet as Worksheet
    Dim toSort as Range

    Set sumSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastCol = sumsheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[a1], _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, 
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set toSort = sumsheet.Rows(1).Resize(1, LastCol - 1).Offset(0, 1)

    toSort.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=toSort, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
     DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Employees").Sort
        .SetRange toSort
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

However the dates moves but don't order as I wish. I think this might have to do with the fact that Excel Sort doesn't know how to handle the dates format, but not sure.

Comment: With exception for column B, they are sorted. I would guess that Excel interpreted B1 as a header. Try setting `.Header = xlNo` intstead of xlGuess

Comment: Column F is also not sorted, as it corresponds to March and appear after June

Answer (score 1):

You should define the format of the data to be sorted. After this line in your code, `toSort.Select`, add this command:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
```

(change the format with appropriate one you use)

Here is the code I used and tested: I got the columns sorted correctly
(change feuil1 to your sheet name)

```
Sub sortByDates()

Dim sumSheet As Range
Dim toSort As Range

'Set sumSheet =
LastCol = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[a1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set toSort = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Resize(1, LastCol - 1).Offset(0, 1)

toSort.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("feuil1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=toSort, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
 DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("feuil1").Sort
    .SetRange toSort
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for the response. However this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please take a look at the code I juste posted, it worked for me